# JQuery capture keydown on check

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Is there any way to capture the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key on an `<input>` element of type `checkbox`?

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="remember" />
```

I have tried this in JavaScript:

```
$('input').on('keydown',function(e){ console.log(e.which)});
```

and it is not working.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Why would you want to capture the Enter key on a checkbox?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swAhu/ your code is working, try to open the fiddle, click anywhere on the body of the result and then click Tab and after that the checkbox will be highlighted then press any button and the key value will be logged.

Comment: I have a form with an invisible submit button, I have some thing to triggering submit button, there is a checkbox in my form i need to triggering my (submit handler) button with enter key on checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is good.  One thing you have wrap it in `$(document).ready..`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
        alert(e.which)
    });
});
```

check in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrKnM/1/)